# Xbox account wont sign in on Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My friend recently got a new Microsoft account and we have been trying to play Minecraft together.

> Minecraft version: Bedrock 1.17, installed on launch

When she tried to sign in, it would send her straight back to the title screen of Minecraft. Does anyone know a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe restart the game. I have switch and when that happens to me, I just restart my game. Then I can sign in. This might not work for you, but it is a suggestion. If I find a better answer, I will edit this answer.

Comment: It doesn't, but thanks anyway!